# How to select HTML structure without an id

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I have the following HTML:

```
    <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button">
      <span class="ui-button-text">New</span>
    </button>
```

This is a button that is created automatically when creating a dialog.  I've tried adding an 'id' in the dialog definition, but this results in a query error.

```
    $("#createDept").dialog({modal:true
                        ,draggable:true
                        ,resizable:false
                         ,position:{my:"center"
                                   ,at:"center"
                                   ,of:window}
                             ,show:"blind"
                             ,hide:"blind"
                           ,height:204
                            ,width:232
                      ,dialogClass:"ui-dialog-osx"
                          ,buttons:{"New":fnClearAllFields
                                      ,id:"btnEdit"
                                ,"Submit":function() {
    ...
    }});
```

The error I get is:

```
    setAttribute — jquery-2.2.1.min.js:3:30983InvalidCharacterError (DOM Exception 5): The string contains invalid characters.
```

So the question is, how can I select the HTML and remove it based on the span content being equal to "New" ?

[Edit]..I can see that the buttons reference is assigned two buttons New and Submit, which I did some time ago and completely forgot about it, so the id is completely in the wrong place.

How do I add an id to the 'New' button ?

I tried:

```
    ,buttons:{"New"{click:fnClearAllFields 
                      ,id:"btnEdit"}}
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: "new" inside buttons object is button name(text) ?
and what is fnClearAllFields

Comment: @IvanKaraman, fnClearAllFields is a function that gets called when the button is clicked on...I think I see the problem now, "Submit" is another button, I missed this, thank you.

Comment: The keys in the `buttons:` object are the labels of the buttons that should be added to the dialog, not attributes of the buttons. And the values are the function that should be called when you click on the button. `btnEdit` is not a function that can be called.

Comment: @Barmar, so how do I add attributes to each button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a single object mapping button labels to callbacks, you need to use an array of objects containing the attributes of each button:

```
buttons: [
    { 
        text: "New",
        id: "btnEdit",
        click: fnClearAllFields
    },
    {
        text: "Submit",
        click: function() {
            ...
        }
    }
]
```

See the example in the jQuery UI [documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-buttons).